# Format dates in Angular based on locale ID

Tags: angular, date, pipe

I am trying to use the Angular DatePipe to display the date based on the selected locale id, so if I say
{{test | date : 'short'}}
I would expect this to pick up the locale set in angular.json 
"i18nLocale": "en-gb"
but it seems to be displaying the US format.

Is there a way of doing this? What if I wanted to use a custom format but changing based on the locale? (for example, dd/MM/yyyy for UK, MM/dd/yyyy for US)?

I am using AOT. My idea is to create a custom pipe that transforms the date but I don't know how to make it pick up the locale ID and I can't find anything in the documentation other than passing the locale every time you use the pipe.
I know I can set the locale ID in the providers of the app but I want to be able to set a different locale in multiple configurations without having to modify the src code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the locale in date pipe by following way.

```
{{test | date : 'short':'en-gb'}}
```

Hope this answer is helpful to you

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to be able to use the locale set in the configuration (ideally in angular.json) to avoid having to pass it every time I use the pipe, also if I do it like this I won't be able to build the app with different locales.

Comment: You could set the locale in an environment variable and then pass that through as part of the ng build - i.e. ng build --configuration=en-gb and have an environment.en-gb.ts.  Everywhere in your build referencing environment.ts will then switch to that config and you only have to maintain the environment variable in one place